# Updating Twitter Status using JTwitter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a code in android that would help update my twitter status from within my app, but am having problems with it.Below is the code snippet

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String statusText = edit.getText().toString();
    new PostToTwitter().execute(statusText);
}

public static String getLogtag() {
    return LOGTAG;
}

class PostToTwitter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
        Twitter twitter = new Twitter("screenname", "password");
        // twitter.getStatus("winterstein");
        twitter.setAPIRootUrl("https://twitter.com/#!/nindevworks");
        twitter.setStatus(params[0]);
        Log.d(TweetActivity.getLogtag(),"Successfully Posted: " + params[0]);
        return "Successfully Posted: " + params[0];
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.e(TweetActivity.getLogtag(),"Died ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed Posting: " + params[0];
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(TweetActivity.this, "result " + result ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

And please could someone explain this portio

Comment: Please use below SO answer's link of twitter integration using twitter4j library, it may help you. [Integrating twitter in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357731/integrating-twitter-in-android/11358052#11358052)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of bugs in your code...

Firstly:

```
Twitter twitter = new Twitter("screenname", "password");
```

You can't use password-based login with Twitter.
(Why does this constructor exists? It's for other services, like Wordpress & identi.ca, which support the Twitter API)

You need to use oauth-based login.

If you've got the latest version of [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php), there's a class called `AndroidTwitterLogin` which you can use to handle the login.

Secondly:

```
twitter.setAPIRootUrl("https://twitter.com/#!/nindevworks");
```

You don't need to set the API root url for Twitter (this is also for Wordpress or identi.ca)

I hope that helps!

Comment: But i think this code should work if you are trying to login some page that supports twitter API. I have the same problem here.